# Splitting the alphabets from numbers in string

Tags: c

Given a string with a combination of alphabets and numbers Ex:ab1c23de5, I need to isolate the numbers and the char from one another in the same string Ex: abcde 12345 . How can this be done in C??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your questions isn't, unfortunately, a good question by the site standards.  Could you spend some time taking a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visiting the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to figure how to ask a good question.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: You may want to view my solution as i had post it for many programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "ab1c23de5";
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < strlen(arr); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(arr[i]))
        {
            printf("Digit %d\n", arr[i] - '0');
        }
        else if (isalpha(arr[i]))
        {
            printf("Alpha %c\n", arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i want the alphabets and numbers splitted and stored in the exact same string!!

Comment: The what is the use of splitting it?

Comment: @user3589002: cf my answer, showing you how to do just that. It offers just one possible solution of many, and it's not _the_ most performant way of doing things, but it's enough to get you started, IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.Matches in C# to make the match. This way the alpha chars is added to list1 and numeric chars is added to list2. Notice the difference inside brackets that makes a pattern for your work.

Using C# for numbers

```
regex = new Regex("[0-9]");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
    //true
}
```

Using C# for alphabets

```
regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
    //true
}
```

Using C for numbers

```
regex_t re;
char file[] = "hello777world99yew 8 I8909do23!";
const char *p = file;
regmatch_t match;

if(regcomp(&re, "[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED) != 0) exit(1);

while(regexec(&re, p, 1, &match, 0) == 0)
{
  printf("%.*s\n", (int)(match.rm_eo - match.rm_so), &p[match.rm_so]);
  p += match.rm_eo;
}
```

Using C for alphabets

```
regex_t re;
    char file[] = "hello777world99yew 8 I8909do23!";
    const char *p = file;
    regmatch_t match;

    if(regcomp(&re, "[a-zA-Z]+", REG_EXTENDED) != 0) exit(1);

    while(regexec(&re, p, 1, &match, 0) == 0)
    {
      printf("%.*s\n", (char)(match.rm_eo - match.rm_so), &p[match.rm_so]);
      p += match.rm_eo;
    }
```

Comment: Except the question is about C and not C#.